# How can I say "not any time soon, but it won't take a long time either"?

Tags: phrases, expression-choice

I was writing an email to a client about a feature we plan to eventually release, maybe in a couple months, but they want some of the functionality now. I initially wrote:

> If there's something else I can do for you, go ahead and let me know. I don't suspect the upgrade will be any time soon.

It sounded like I was saying the upgrade will take a long time, but that's not what I want to imply. I almost wrote:

> I don't suspect the upgrade will be any time **immediately soon**.

...which sounds awkward, and I don't think it's correct. The [search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22immediately%20soon%22) I got for the term support my assumption.

What would be a better way to say "not soon, but fairly soon" in this context?

Comment: Ah, a downvote by the third view. Is this a bad question? I'm happy to remove it, but if someone would be so kind as to enlighten me about my fault I would appreciate it very much. Maybe the answer is obvious and I just have a mental block?

Comment: @KristinaLopez You merely changed "be" for "happen"? Don't you think both ways make it sound like the upgrade will take a long time? Often people say "it won't happen any time soon" in an almost sarcastic way to mean that it will *never* happen. I want the customer to know that it will be soon, but not so soon that they shouldn't send me support requests for their current product. It *is* in process, but not likely to be complete before they need some of the functionality that it will offer. Can you suggest another phrase that will instill a bit more confidence?

Comment: @KristinaLopez I like your suggestion: *"I don't suspect the upgrade will be in the immediate future."* It's exactly what I was looking for; not too pessimistic but not promising anything either. If you post it as an answer I will accept it. It's a perfect swap-out: "any time soon" -> "in the immediate future".

Comment: When expressing such doubts, it's normal to say *"I **suspect** it **won't** happen any time soon"*, or *"I **don't expect**"* it **will** happen any time soon*. To my (British) ear, *"I **don't suspect** blah blah"* sounds at least slightly "odd", though I can't say exactly why.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That also sounds perfect. For whatever reason, I find *"I suspect it won't"* a bit more optimistic than *"I don't suspect it will"* (which is what I was going for, as this is directed to a customer).

Comment: Aside: I find it strange that searching Google for "immediately soon" brings up loads of results for porn sites... or is that my tailored search result? ;)

Comment: @Wesley: Now you point it out, I'm inclined to agree *suspect it won't* is potentially at least less "blunt/harsh/pessimistic". But regardless of that, when the negating *won't/don't* is brought forward, I don't much like *don't suspect*. I guess I'm just more used to hearing *don't **expect*** there. As regards "immediately soon" though, I wouldn't expect them to occur consecutively except when separated by some form of punctuation; they are not natural bedfellows.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Either one sounds right to me, but *"expect"* does sound better. Yes *"immediately soon"* was just grasping at straws, hoping to explain what I was going for. I Googled it with much doubt.

Comment: The following is what sparked me to research this particular situation. I was sending a reply to earlier email when at the end of my statement, I wished to put in writing something that is said in my cultural vernacular all of the time with the correct understanding to the hearer of the statement. It went like this; I was telling the recipient of my email that I would eventually get around to researching the subject of the email, but that it wouldn't be immediately. So I started to phase it like this: "I will do some research on this and send you the information, but it won't be right away. Bu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to say it where it doesn't sound so distantly in the future is to say, ***"The upgrade will not happen in the immediate future."***

(thanks Wesley!)

Comment: If you want to sound a little more hopeful, you can add a "but it's coming" to the end of this. "...The upgrade will not happen in the immediate future, but it is coming."

Comment: @Marthaª The thing about that is, it doesn't give you an out if the upgrade never happens, while "it won't happen soon" does. ;)

Comment: This is a passive sentence and makes it seem as though the upgrade happens via some force over which you have no control.  Considering that you are doing the upgrade, I think you would want something such a bit more active.  I'm answering below.

Answer (score 2):

***The upgrade is not imminent.***

> **imminent** (*adj*.) liable to happen soon [[Collins]](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/imminent); likely or certain to happen very soon [[Macmillan]](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/imminent)

If you want, you could add some reassurances to the end:

> *The upgrade is not imminent, but it's coming.*

Answer (score 0):

From a client's perspective, an actual time frame is far more meaningful than any formulation intended to convey "soon but not right away." If you hope that the upgrade will be available within two months but you recognize that it may slip a bit from that schedule, I would recommend expressing the time frame as follows:

> We expect to have the upgrade ready within three months—and if all goes well, within two months.

This has the advantage of offering your client a realistic idea of the probable range of completion dates, without absolutely promising anything.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a timeframe, and don't wish to imply that there is one.

Comment: If you don't have a time frame, how do you know that—by the customer's reckoning—getting the feature ready to ship "won't take a long time"? My answer attempts to address the problem of the fundamental subjectivity of "a long time" when it isn't moored to any objective measure of time. I've been on the customer end of assurances of the type described here, and I think it's much more annoying to be told that something "won't take a long time" and then to find that it does take (what I consider) a long time than to be told up-front, "I'm sorry but I can't give you a time frame for that."

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

If there is something else I can do for you, please let me know.  Although the upgrade is not available yet, it soon will be.

Comment: A bit too optimistic for my taste, but yes this would work, although telling them that the upgrade is not available yet seems a bit obvious.

Comment: Apart from not getting the timing right, this is a run-on sentence.

Comment: @Marthaª:  I don't agree.  The sentence is fine as is.

Comment: You could make my suggestion less optimistic by adding the words "we hope" to it:  If there is something else I can do for you, please let me know.  Although the upgrade is not available yet, we hope it soon will be.

Answer (score 0):

I might say that the upgrade will "take a while". While "a while" is not exactly a long time,  it does mean an appreciable amount in this usage. Like this:

> If there's something else I can do for you, go ahead and let me know. I suspect the upgrade will **take a while**.

Comment: This works too, thanks. I suppose it's a pretty dumb question on my part as this seems to be kind of an obvious way to put it, I guess I was looking for something that says "it's coming soon, but I have no idea know when".

Comment: This implies specifically that it *will* probably take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

By sticking with a passive sentence structure ("will be"), you're dodging the issue and, if I may be so bold, leaving out information that your customer may need to know.  I would recommend changing  this to an active sentence and actually including some information.  After reading over comments, perhaps something like:

> [We're waiting on a 3rd party for some reason.  We're not sure how
>   much time the 3rd party will need.  As soon as this condition is met,]
>   **we will perform the upgrade in a matter of [minutes/hours/days].**  [We
>   don't think this will be a problem for you, let us know if this is
>   incorrect.]

Comment: As much as I'd like to get your response on some new feature, if I were the client, there's nothing in the OP's question to imply anything definite that can be committed to on that new feature. Actually the OP says as much in the comments under the question.

Comment: @KristinaLopez then perhaps "[As soon as some condition is met] we will perform the upgrade" or "start the upgrade process."

Comment: Absolutely, if that condition is known.  My experience with software support is that you sometimes need to make vague assurances in the absence of any firm commitment. :-)

Comment: True of many business cases.  But with all due respect (and just at the fringe of applicability to this question) I would hope that anyone making such a statement knew which condition he or she was waiting on.  Otherwise . . . ?  I understand that the OP has little/no control over the 3rd party, but does have current information about this work and will react as appropriate.